# Does Ada have a type equivalent to Pascal's set?

Tags: ada

I'm learning Ada as a spare-time activity and, while I realise that it is greatly inspired by Pascal, I can't find a type that is similar to Pascal's `set`.

`set` is built into the Pascal language itself and uses one bit per element. So, for example, `var a: set of char;` declares a (typically) 256-bit data type that can hold any set of characters.

In Ada, I can see that it has sets as part of its library (not a built-in language feature) but those are more like Java's `HashSet` or C++'s `unordered_set` and take up much more memory than 1 bit per element. Am I missing something?

Comment: For bit-wise operations, also consider a _modular type_, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bada%5D+modular+bit).

Comment: Ada 83 tended not to include things that the user can easily implement, so it did not have much of a standard library, which was probably a mistake. Since a generic package implementing such bit-mapped sets can easily be implemented, Ada did not include it. You can find such a package at [PragmARC.Data_Structures.Sets.Discrete](https://github.com/jrcarter/PragmARC/blob/Ada-12/pragmarc-data_structures-sets-discrete.ads).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Boolean array to get an equivalent type:

```
type Element is (A, B, C, D);
-- The possible elements of the sets.

type Set is array (Element) of Boolean;
-- A set of Elements. An Element E is in the
-- set S if and only if S(E) is True.

B_and_D : Set := (B | D => True, others => False);
--  A set initialized to contain B and D.
```

If you want to store the elements in single bits, add "with Pack" to the declaration of type Set. For example, if you want a set of Characters, using 256 bits, that would be

```
type Char_Set is array (Character) of Boolean
with Pack;
```

Comment: Note that the one-dimensional arrays of Boolean can also be operated on with the logical "and", "or", "xor", "not" operators, which then apply element-per-element. If the arrays represent sets, these operators implement set intersection, set union, symmetric set difference, and set complement, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't come across the "with pack" syntax before, but it looks like what I was looking for. Does `with pack` have exactly the same effect as `pragma pack` I had learned about pragma pack at [adacore](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/representation_clauses_and_pragmas.html) but had never heard of "with pack" until now.

Comment: Yes, pragma Pack and "with Pack" are just two ways to set the "Pack" aspect of the type. However, the pragma form is considered obsolete (see http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-J-15-3.html).

Comment: Just for completeness, note that the Ada standard does not absolutely require compilers to pack to the bit level, although it is recommended. If you want to be sure that your compiler does bit-level packing, you can specify Size in addition to Pack, for example "type Char_Set ... with Pack, Size => 256". If the compiler accepts that, there is one bit per element.

Comment: You can also specify `Component_Size => 1` to obtain bit packing.

Answer (score 1):

For `Character`, you can find a predefined type, `Character_Set`, in package `Ada.Strings.Maps`.

You will also find predefined sets like `Lower_Set`, `Upper_Set`, `Alphanumeric_Set` in `Ada.Strings.Maps.Constants`

Answer (score -2):

All you want to know on Ada :
[AdaCore](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/index.html)
specifically the paragraph on typing :
[AdaCore Typing](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/strongly_typed_language.html)

Comment: Could you please replace the „enter link description here“ parts with actual link descriptions?  Also just links to other web pages are kind of fragile. At least summarize or selectively quote what it says there, please.

Comment: -For reason i don't understand, the 2 links are efficient but the text is bad & I can't change this, i tried few times before publishing ! Subject is complicated, typing is the basis of Ada. Requestor needs necessarily to start from basis & it's exactly what the AdaCore courses do. I would add that the discussion of typing implementation is not Ada philosophy. Ada does the job & the way to do it isn't really important.   Except you need to write low level code as drivers by ex. ! You need before to have very good basis in typing. -Following courses, he will have answers, no other solution.